How to add new folder in existing github repository and push new solution to that folder with VS2022
I can not make push with SSH, because I have Github authorisation through https://www.office.com, this authorisation working with browser.
I have download existing project with structure:
solution 
   solution file
   - project folder 1
   - project folder 2
   - project folder 3

In my local computer I have create new solution in new folder XXX with my new code
solution 
   solution file
   - project folder 1
   - project folder 2
   - project folder 3
   - new folder XXX
     -- solution file
     -- project folder 1
     -- project folder 2
     -- project folder 3

But how to push my new XXX folder to remote Github repository?
I can push some files to top folder, but pushing of my new folder XXX is impossible, I don't see any my new code from XXX folder in Github. I have created new branch, and want to push my new folder XXX (and 3 subfolder with projects inside it) to new branch, but don't understand how to do this.
What I need to click in VS 2022 to push exactly my new folder XXX to new branch?
